# Как сравнить два словаря python и узнать каких ключей нет в том или ином словаре

Tags: python, python-3.x, dict, условия

У меня есть два словаря python:

```
pp = {'title': 'jr', 'description': '64', 'price': '3'}
cc = {'python': 'dede', 'key:': '#789', 'title': 'jr', 'description': '64', 'price': '3'}
```

Мне необходимо написать код, который мог бы отображать ключ которого нет в другом словаре, как это можно сделать?

В качестве результата должно получиться:

```
"key ['python'] not in dict ['cc']"   # написал для примера
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно через множества получить разницу в ключах словарей

Пример:

```
d1 = {'title': 'jr', 'description': '64', 'price': '3'}
d2 = {'python': 'dede', 'key:': '#789', 'title': 'jr', 'description': '64', 'price': '3'}

result = set(d1).difference(set(d2))
if result:
    print(f'В d2 нет ключей d1: {result}')
else:
    print('В d1 все ключи d2')

result = set(d2).difference(set(d1))
if result:
    print(f'В d1 нет ключей d2: {result}')
else:
    print('В d2 все ключи d1')
```

Результат:

```
В d1 все ключи d2
В d1 нет ключей d2: {'key:', 'python'}
```

---

**UPD.**

Вместо `difference` можно использовать оператор `-`, пример:

```
result = set(d1) - set(d2)
```

Comment: пожалуйста добавьте в ответ информацию о том, как понять где чего нет

Comment: @MaximChyorny, добавил пример. А так, логика `difference` такая: из левой части удаляются элементы правой и возвращаются те, что остались в левой части. Например, при `{1, 2, 3} - {2, 3, 4}` из левой части будут удалены 2 и 3, и останется 1, результат `{1}`

Answer (score 5):

Ключи словаря - это множество. Множества можно вычитать:

```
a = {'title': 'jr', 'description': '64', 'price': '3'}
b = {'python': 'dede', 'key:': '#789', 'title': 'jr', 'description': '64', 'price': '3'}
print(a.keys()-b.keys())
print(b.keys()-a.keys())
```

Вывод:

```
set()
{'python', 'key:'}
```

Т.е. в данном случае множество ключей первого словаря целиком есть во втором словаре.
А вот во втором словаре не хватает двух ключей относительно первого словаря.

Comment: +1, не знал, что ключи словаря могут играть роль множества, точнее что этим занимается тип `dict_keys`, хотя проверку `isinstance` на `set` проваливает :)

Comment: @gil9red Да я сам немного удивился, что к множеству не нужно приводить, проверил на всякий - и так прокатило )